# Error when I try to iterate in dict : it's showing unsupported operand type

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got this program which calculate Euclidean similarity.

```
from math import sqrt

def leeValoraciones(nomFichero):
    lineas = [(l.strip()).split("\t") for l in (open(nomFichero).readlines())]
    diccio = {}
    for l in lineas:    
        diccio[int(l[0])] = {}
    for l in lineas:
        diccio[int(l[0])][int(l[1])] = (float(l[2]),float(l[3]))
    return diccio

def euclideanDist(dic1, dic2):
    # Compute the sum of squares of the elements common
    # to both dictionaries
    sum2 = sum([pow(dic1[elem]-dic2[elem], 2)
                for elem in dic1 if elem in dic2])
    return sqrt(sum2)

def euclideanSimilarity(dic1, dic2):
    return 1/(1+euclideanDist(dic1, dic2))

diccio = leeValoraciones("u.data")
diccio2 = leeValoraciones("u.data")


euclideanSimilarity(diccio,diccio2)
```

When I run the program it returns me the following error:

```
for elem in dic1 if elem in dic2])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that elem is a dict and you can't ask if a dict is whitin another dict using `in` operator.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate the distance between here? You pass in two dictionaries, both built from the *exact same file*; any distances between the contained points will be 0 as they are the same points.

Comment: The Euclidian distance normally takes *two* points with the same number of coordinates, like `(x, y, z)` and calculates the distance from that. You are passing in a series of points instead, treating them both as if they each were a single point.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer dictionaries contain nested dictionaries. You are trying to subtract those:

```
for l in lineas:    
    diccio[int(l[0])] = {}
for l in lineas:
    diccio[int(l[0])][int(l[1])] = (float(l[2]),float(l[3]))
```

So your dictionary has the structure `{integer: {integer: (float, float)}}` but you only loop over the outer dictionary. Not that you can subtract the innermost tuples either.

You perhaps should use the two integers as coordinates instead, giving you one outer dictionary pointing to tuples of floats, in the form `{(integer, integer): (float, float)}`.

You can achieve this with just the one loop over a file, there isn't really a need to loop twice (or read all lines into memory first). Using the `csv` module helps get the lines read into rows:

```
import csv

def leeValoraciones(nomFichero):
    with open(nomFichero, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        results = {}
        for row in reader:
            key = tuple(int(c) for c in row[:2])
            value = tuple(float(c) for c in row[2:4])
            results[key] = value
    return results
```

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to calculate a Euclidian distance with here; you pass in the two dictionaries both built from the exact same file. The Euclidian distance between all the points of those two files will be exactly 0.

As stated, you cannot use the `(float, float)` tuples as a single point in Euclidian space, you have a *series* of points. You need to decide between what points you'd calculate the distance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, is this the entire program, if not, please post the entire program. Secondly, I believe , from your error that is, that `for elem in dic1 if elem in dic2])` should be

```
for elem in dic1:
    if elem in dic2:
       Do things
```

Third and finally, your error there is saying you are attempting to subtract dictionaries, which doesn't make sense. Try instead

```
for elem in dic1:
    if elem in dic2:
       dic1[elem]-dict2[elem]
```

Now, this answer may be totally wrong, but this is what it appears to be from what you have posted. Please post the entire code, and also the contents of u.data

Comment: those are called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and are more Pythonic (and generally faster) than nested `for` loops.

Comment: @MattDMo:Huh, I didn't know that. Thank you, that is actually fairly awesome and useful to know.